# Find the integer part of the sum $S=\sum_{k=1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt k} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{80} \frac{1}{\sqrt k}.$$Then I would like to obtain $\lfloor S \rfloor$, the integer part of $S$.

I am not able to think how to start question .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums   Read some examples at this page. Hope it might work.

Comment: In which context is the question asked? The dirty solution is simply using a calculator: $\left \lfloor{S}\right \rfloor
 =16$.

Comment: Well S is less than $\sum 1/\rfloor \sqrt k \lfloor $ and greater than $\sum 1/\rceil \sqrt k \lceil $.  For the n^2 <= k <= n^2 + 2n +1 you will have 2n summands each either 1/n or 1/n+1.  So S is between $\sum_{1..9} 2n/n $ and $\sum_{1..9} 2n/(n+1) $.  Or so... I was sloppy so I probably made some indexing errors.

Comment: @Αδριανός Offtopic, more than overkill, I would say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An elementary way.

One may observe that, for $k=1,2,\cdots$,
$$
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}},\quad \sqrt{k+1/2}-\sqrt{k-1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+1/2}+\sqrt{k-1/2}}
$$ and that
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}} <\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}< \frac1{\sqrt{k+\frac12}+\sqrt{k-\frac12}}
$$ giving, for $k=1,2,\cdots$,
$$
2\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)<\frac1{\sqrt{k}}< 2\left(\sqrt{k+\frac12}-\sqrt{k-\frac12}\right)
$$

then one may conclude with [telescoping sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html):

> $$
> 2\sqrt{n+1}-2<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{n+\frac12}-\sqrt{2},\quad n\ge1.
> $$

Taking $n=80$ gives
$$
\color{blue}{16}<\sum_{k=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}<\color{blue}{16}.5301\cdots.
$$

One may observe that
$$
 \left|\left(2\sqrt{n+\frac12}-\sqrt{2}\right)-(2\sqrt{n+1}-2)\right|<2-\sqrt{2}<1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we get $$S\left(N\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{N}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{3/2}}dt
 $$ so, using the bounds $t-1\leq\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we have $$2\sqrt{N}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}-2\leq S(N)\leq2\sqrt{N}-1
 $$ hence $$\color{red}{\left\lfloor S\left(80\right)\right\rfloor =16.}$$