# Finding summation of inverse of square roots.

Tags: radicals

Problem:  Find the integer part of
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000000}}$$

How should I go about approaching this question?  I have never seen such a question before, where you cannot multiply any conjugate or whatsoever.  What is the method to go about approaching such problems?

Comment: Experiments with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fsqrt(i),+i+from+1+to+1000000) has let me to believe that the integer part of your sum, in general from $\frac1{\sqrt1}$ to $\frac1{\sqrt{a^{2n}}}$, is $2\cdot a^n - 2$ (integers $a, n$). I have no idea how to prove it, though. The integral $\int_1^{2n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}dx$ gives an approximation, but going from there to the exact integer part...

Comment: You can try the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: Several similar posts:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854810/find-the-integer-part-of-the-sum-s-sum-k-180-frac1-sqrt-k,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410336/what-is-the-integer-part-of-sum-i-29999-frac-1-sqrt-i,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727376/find-formula-for-frac1-sqrt-1-frac1-sqrt-2-cdots-frac1-sqrt-n?noredirect=1&lq=1,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168520/find-the-value-of-left-frac1-sqrt-2-frac1-sqrt-3-frac1-s?rq=1,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522888/left-lfloor-frac1-sqrt1-frac1-sqrt2-frac1-sqrt3-frac1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516846/how-to-find-lfloor-1-sqrt11-sqrt2-dots1-sqrt100-rfloor-without-a?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By integration of

$$\frac1{\sqrt x}\le\frac1{\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}}<\frac1{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

we establish a formula for the tail of the summation,

$$\int_m^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}\le\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<\int_m^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-1}},$$ or

$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt m)\le\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<2(\sqrt n-\sqrt{m-1}).$$

Then for the complete sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{\sqrt k}+2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt m)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{\sqrt k}+2(\sqrt n-\sqrt{m-1}).$$

We can compute the bracketing for increasing $m$, and it turns out that $m=2$ suffices to establish

$$1998.17257288\le S<1999.0$$

Hence, $$\color{green}{1998}.$$

---

For safety, with $m=3$,

$$1998.24400517\le S<1998.87867966$$

---

**Rationale of the method:**

An integral approximates a sum inasmuch as the function value remains sufficiently constant in unit intervals. In the case of the inverse square root, the error per interval is

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac1{\sqrt n}=O(n^{-3/2}),$$ which decreases relatively quickly. So there is some hope that by combining a direct summation of the first terms and a bracketing of the tail, we can end up with the two bounds in the same unit interval so that we know the integer part. (The last terms won't be a problem as they correspond to a tiny error.)

We are pretty lucky here as the unit interval is found with very few terms.

---

Given that the width of the bracketing is

$$2(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt m-\sqrt{m-1}),$$ we can conclude as soon as the partial sum differs from an integer by more than this amount. And the firt parial sums are approximately

$$1,1.71,2.28,2.78,3.23\cdots$$

which leave a good margin.

Comment: Simple and nice (as usual). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: greetings, Claude. My secret (maybe I already said it): I am unable to do complicated things ;-)

Comment: For instance if it were to change to + then -, would the approach be the same?

Comment: @XcoderX: then you would take the terms two by two to get rid of the alternation (and get a yet faster convergence).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I asked about zeta for real arguments between 0 and 1 a few days ago. Good answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597478/riemann-zeta-for-real-argument-between-0-and-1-using-mellin-with-short-asymptot

Comment: @WillJagy. Thanks for the link. It is very interesting (question and answers).

Answer (score 14):

For an precalculus (telescoping) approach.
Notice that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}>\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$$
From this $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{1000^2}}\geq 2(\sqrt 2-1+\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2+\cdots+\sqrt{1000^2+1}-\sqrt{1000^2})\geq 2\sqrt{1000^2+1}-2>2000-2=1998$$
And also $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1}}=2(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1})$$
Leaving the $n=1$ case alone we get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{1000^2}}<1+2(\sqrt 2-1+\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2+\cdots \sqrt{1000^2}-\sqrt{1000^2-1})=1+2\sqrt{1000^2}-2=1999$$

And it follows that the integer part is $1998$

Answer (score 10):

If you know about generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {\sqrt k}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Now, using the asymptotics
$$S_n=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac1 {2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ where $\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx -1.46035$.

SO, if $n=10^6$, the approximation gives for your summation $\approx \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{4000001}{2000}\approx 1998.54$ while the rigorous calculation would give ... the same value !

**Edit** *(five years later)*

To answer a question asked in private, considering the more general case of
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {\sqrt[a] k}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$ using asymptotics
$$\color{blue}{n^{\frac{1}{a}} \left(S_n-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)=}$$ $$\color{blue}{\frac{a n}{a-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12 a
   n}+\frac 1{720}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\, \frac{\prod_{m=1}^{2k} (a m+1) } {\alpha_k\,(an)^{2k+1} }}$$

where the $\alpha_k$ form the sequence
$$\{1,42,1680,66528,1816214400,103783680,14820309504000,\cdots\}$$

Multiplied by $720$, you will find them in sequence $A060055$ in $OEIS$.